# ¿Como colocar el comando php en el git bash en Windows?

Tags: php, windows, git, bash

Como usar el comando de PHP en la Bash de Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder usar el comando de PHP en el Bash de Git (Git Bash) hay que ejecutar este comando:

```
alias php='C:/xampp/php/php.exe'
```

Lo que va entre las comillas simples es la dirección donde se encuentra el ejecutable de PHP.

Comment: ¿Y si no tienes instalado XAMPP?

Comment: Simplemente busca la ubicación de el php.exe